# Spring Boot: Exception Handling if mongo diconnects after application start up

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, exception, spring-session

My spring boot application uses mongo during startup and it start very smoothly.
Now after start up I Shut the mongo and hit any controller of my application. But the control never reaches to the controller level Hence mongo exception can not be handled by @ControllerAdvice.
I have also tried to make a generic exception handler and registered that class in application.java like this

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

    return container -> {
        ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,"/error");
        container.addErrorPages(error401Page);
    };
```

This works fine as long as mongo is up and running.
Once mongo is down I get the following stack trace

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:77)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2114)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1904)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1712)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:636)
org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoOperationsSessionRepository.findSession(MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java:127)
org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java:78)
org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java:44)
org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:326)
org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:343)
org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:214)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:255)
org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getSessionId(WebUtils.java:288)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1077)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:187)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:170)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:134)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

**JBWEB000071: root cause**

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
    com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
    com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
    com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
    com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:210)
    com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:482)
    com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:79)
    com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
    com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:777)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:747)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:694)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2143)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2127)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1901)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1712)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:636)
    org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoOperationsSessionRepository.findSession(MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java:127)
    org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java:78)
    org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java:44)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:326)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:343)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:214)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:255)
    org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getSessionId(WebUtils.java:288)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1077)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:134)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

For every controller I am getting this stack trace. I want to handle this gracefully. Please suggest at what point I should handle mongo connection exceptions after application startup. I am using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb maven dependency for my project

Comment: `SessionRepositoryFilter` http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.html is the code that fails here. It executes before any controller-related machinery (including advices) may come into play, so if it fales, it does so before any controller scope is created. Where do you have that filter configured?

Comment: This is my security config

Comment: I am using @EnableMongoHttpSession which creates a Spring Bean with the name of springSessionRepositoryFilter that implements Filter. The filter is what is in charge of replacing the HttpSession implementation to be backed by Spring Session. In this instance Spring Session is backed by Mongo. as mentioned http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SessionRepositoryFilter` http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/… added by your `@EnableMongoHttpSession` is the code that fails here. It executes before any controller-related machinery (including advices) may come into play, so if it fails, it does so before any controller scope is created.

But you can create a filter, insert it into filter chain before Mongo Http Session filter and try to catch and handle that exception:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (TranslatedException e) {
        // somehow handle it, like display an error message
    }
}
```

where `TranslatedException` is the exception to which spring translates `MongoTimeoutException` (it cannot be seen from your stack trace).

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me :). But we cannot set any content in response to show internal server error or Service unavailable error